# Is this PHP approach safe?

Tags: php

I want to send a number of parameters from an application to a database table through PHP.
I use the 'GET' method and want to set some restrictions to the variables and/or in some way make it safe as in the approach below.
The good thing is that they can only contain greek letters, numbers and the .-, symbols.

Is this doing it correctly?

FORM:

```
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type=text" name="b">
```

URL:

```
http://the url.php?a=4,52&b=αβγδ.,-12345
```

What I want it to do, simply:

Show rows where id=x if the user sends an existing id and the correct key that is defined in the PHP file.

Safe approach [edited]:

```
$dbh=db_conn();

$vara = mb_convert_encoding($_GET["a"], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-7');
$varb = mb_convert_encoding($_GET["b"], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-7');

$sqlb = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND $vara='myknowkey';");

$sqlb->execute($varb);
```

Comment: Why are you substituting `$_GET['a']` straight into the SQL rather than having it as a parameter like `$_GET['b']`?

Comment: @IMSoP Because you can't use prepared statements to place a condition on an arbitrary column.

Comment: Why this question is tagged with prepared statement?

Comment: @Niet whare is a condition on an arbitrary column here?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I thought that might be the intention, but it doesn't make sense with the example given, where `$_GET['a']` is `'4,52'`.

Comment: Why on the earth to upvote *such* a duplicate?

Comment: True, I agree, it doesn't make much sense. But at least that should explain why they're trying to do this... hopefully!

Comment: @YourCommonSense `$dbh->prepare()` sure looks like a Prepared Statement to me. Not the most *useful* tag, but not completely irrelevant.

Comment: Sidenote: You have a typo `<input type=text" name="b">` missing quote `<input type="text" name="b">` so that will throw an error, in case that is your actual code. Notice SO's syntax highlighting? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

no,
`$_GET[a]='myknowkey'` can inject code to your sql statement